# Virtuoso Bulk Loader Syntax error. Is there a way to skip invalid lines?

Tags: rdf, virtuoso, triplestore

I have got a big data set (compressed nquads) of dumps. Unfortunately some lines do not match the syntax settings of Virtuoso Loader.

```
Virtuoso Open Source Edition (Column Store) (multi threaded)
Version 7.2.0.3212-pthreads as of Feb 23 2015
```

e.g.

`_:node123 <http://url.org/Person/name> "Dave"@en,ja,es <http://www.someurl.cc>  .`

I get the following error in log file:

`15:22:50 PL LOG:  File 00000.gz error 37000 SP029: NQuads RDF loader, line 133081: syntax error processed pending to here.`

1. Is there a way to just skip the invalid* line and continue loading the rest of the file?
2. Is there any way of loading the whole file other than writing a script that fixes this syntax error* in all dump files?

* other validators do show that line as valid

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions are often better raised on the public [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).  (ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software, producer of Virtuoso.)

Comment: That said, near as I can tell from [the NQuads spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/), `"Dave"@en,ja,es` is not a valid string literal; there is no provision for multiple languages in a single langtag (`LANGTAG ::= '@' [a-zA-Z]+ ('-' [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`).  You need 3 statements for the 3 `rdf:langString` values -- `"Dave"@en`, `"Dave"@ja`, `"Dave"@es`.

Comment: In dealing with this and many other issues, it is very helpful to know the exact version and build of Virtuoso -- most easily gotten from output of `virtuoso-t -?` or `virtuoso-iodbc-t -?`...

Comment: Worth noting, you're running off a 15-month-old codebase.  [VOS is now at 7.2.4.3217](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/ChangeLog), which update is recommended for all users.

Comment: Thank you TallTed. I know, that it might not be valid, but I still need/want to import as much data as possible without quitting the loader at the first error that occurs. PS: I did the update to 7.2.4.

Comment: We will likely be tweaking the NQuad loader to handle this langtag-list data, even though technically invalid. We may also be tweaking the load routines to continue row-by-row data file loads, probably with an optional output of ignored/bad rows encountered during such load. Priority of each of these tweaks will depend in part on user/customer interest, so I again suggest you raise this issue [directly against the GitHub project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/) and/or [in an OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: Thank you TallTed, I did post the question to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/35056846/). I got an answer with some solutions that helped me a lot!